# SQL: How do i rename an SQL case statement and still be able to group it

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(median_age) 'Frequency',  
    CASE  
        WHEN median_age < 20 THEN 'Terrible'  
        WHEN median_age < 30 THEN 'Low'  
        WHEN median_age < 40 THEN 'Medium'  
        ELSE 'High'  
    END Life_Expectancy    
FROM countries  
GROUP BY Life_Expectancy    
ORDER BY median_age;
```

Sorry in advance if this has been asked before im new to this site and SQL.
The Above code works perfectly however my column name is Life_expectancy.
I can change the END line to 'Life Expectancy' which is my aim. However when i do this i can no longer group my data in the GROUP BY line. If i try to group by 'Life Expectancy' it simply averages all my data which isnt very usefull.

Desired output: Currently acheived with above code
Frequency   Life_Expectancy
32  Terrible
63  Low
57  Medium
49  High

Output if i change it to 'Life Expectancy':
Frequency   Life Expectancy
201     Medium

Comment: What is your SQL version (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: I do see no use of the SQL function [AVG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg)), and please add the RDBMS you ar using and some sample input and desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am currently working on Khan Academy, so i dont know how to answer your question

Comment: @luuk How did you format it so nicely for starters?

Comment: for formatting posts see: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I thought the notation `[Life Expectancy]` (with hooks) would have worked

Comment: @Christophe: If you are using a microsoft product (like MSSQL, or Access), then you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the alias name in quotes:

```
SELECT COUNT(median_age) 'Frequency',  
    CASE WHEN median_age < 20 THEN 'Terrible'  
         WHEN median_age < 30 THEN 'Low'  
         WHEN median_age < 40 THEN 'Medium'  
         ELSE 'High'  
    END AS "Life Expectancy"
FROM countries  
GROUP BY 2   
ORDER BY
    CASE "Life Expectancy" WHEN 'Terrible' THEN 1
                           WHEN 'Low' THEN 2
                           WHEN 'Medium' THEN 3
                           ELSE 4 END;
```

The ugliness of the `ORDER BY` clause has to do with that the only things which can appear there are the count and the aliased `Life Expectancy`.  So using my approach I was forced to derive another `CASE` expression to generate the desired ordering.

Comment: This works thanks, now for me to figure out why. If i dont order it originally it seems to work fine but in other cases the order is needed?